# How to bind several selectors in jquery to specific data in only one ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have a button which send me the values of input checkboxes via an ajax call.

```
<input type="checkbox" class="delete" value="PHP" /> PHP <br />  
<input type="checkbox" class="delete" value="ASP" /> ASP <br />

<button type="button" class="checkbox_value_delete">Delete</button>
```

The ajax:

```
$('.checkbox_value_delete').click(function(){  
       var checkboxes_delete = []; 
   $('.delete').each(function(){  
            if($(this).is(":checked")) {  
                 checkboxes_delete.push($(this).val());                      
            }  
   });
   checkboxes_delete = checkboxes_delete.toString();
     $.ajax({  
            url:"",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:{ checkboxes_delete:checkboxes_delete },  
            success:function(data){  
                 $('.result').html(data);  
            }  
     });  
});
```

This works fine!

Now i want to add to more buttons and bind the selectors to the data in the same ajax call. is that possible or do i have to create 3 standalone ajaxes for this?.

Buttons:

```
<button type="button" class="checkbox_value_delete">Delete</button>  
<button type="button" class="checkbox_value_copy">Copy</button>  
<button type="button" class="checkbox_value_move">Move</button>
```

Something like below:

```
$('.checkbox_value_delete, checkbox_value_copy, checkbox_value_move ').click(function(){  
       var checkboxes_delete = []; // bind to 1st selector
       var checkboxes_copy = []; // bind to 2nd selector
       var checkboxes_move = []; // bind to 3rd selector
       // and so on...
```

Comment: Given that "delete", "copy", and "move" and fairly distinct operations, it doesn't make sense to have a combined event handler, which will have to determine which one was clicked to know what to do.  You *can*, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Also side note; `$(this).is(":checked")` can be just `this.checked`  `checked` is a property on checkbox Elements.  There's no need to perform the jQuery instantiation and pseudoselector just to get the boolean property that already exists.  Edit: otherwise `$('.delete:checked')` and remove the inner if

Comment: @Taplar Ok. Thnx. I will make 3 single ajax calls for each.

Comment: If there is common logic between the three event handlers, by all means extract that out into a common method (or methods) that all three event handlers can use, but don't put them all in a single handler that makes you perform more work figuring out what you actually need to do.